# Zenject: FromMethod and OnInstantiated

Tags: unity-game-engine, zenject

using this kind of contstruction:

```
Container.Bind<Freeman>()
        .FromMethod(_ => { return Container.InstantiatePrefabForComponent<Freeman>(freemanPrefab); })
        .AsTransient()
        .OnInstantiated<Freeman>((injCtx, freeman) =>
        {
            Debug.Log(freeman.name);
        });
```

The Debug.Log never works meaning the OnInstantiated never being called. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue too. In my case I didn't inject binded class. And as it binds lazily by default I had to add .NonLazy() instruction at the end of the binding.
Hope this reminder will help to someone to save precious minutes.
Cheers. :)